# Bind 2 network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, iperf

I have a PC1 connected to a PC2 through Ethernet.
The PC2 has also a WiFi interface and is connected to a WiFi network.
A PC3 is also connected to the same WiFi network.

So, it looks like this :
PC1 <-----eth-----> PC2 <----wlan----> PC3

The ethernet and WLAN interfaces don't use the same subnet (**192.168.1.X** for Ethernet and **192.168.2.X** for WLAN). Now I want to use PC1 as a iperf server and PC3 as a iperf client, the PC2 being just a bridge.

Let's say that PC1 IP address is **192.168.1.5** and PC3 IP address is **192.168.2.5**

If I do

(on PC1) : `iperf -s –u –w 64k`

(on PC3) : `iperf -c 192.168.1.5 -b 75M –w 64k`

obviously, the client (PC3) won't be able to find the server (PC1). My question is how it is possible to bind the interface eth0 and wlan0 on the PC2 so it behaves like a bridge for the iperf test?

Comment: this is more of an admin question so you may get better results looking at a site addressing it. but  pc2 needs to have forwarding turned on (sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1   depending on your linux flavor ) and you might need explicit routes. you would need to test.